# How large is the storage space of ubuntu 1 free? (How many GB do I have)?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I know that google's my friend, but I didn't find the answer to this simple question anywhere.  Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 4):

[Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) has right now a 5GB Storage for Free (After you register).

When registering you will also have the possibility to choose between other non-free [storage options](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/), like 20GB for Music streaming.

There is also an [Invite Friends Get More Space!](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/08/15/invite-your-friends-and-get-more-free-storage/) idea available. So 5GB is not the limit.

I enjoy Ubuntu One since it saves many home folder files so when I format/install from scratch I can just update them from the Ubuntu One directly.

Answer (score 2):

Register to **[Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/)** and you will get 5GB storage for free.

Free Package

- File sync across platforms
- 5 GB of Storage
- Share folders and files
- Access on your mobile

**You're in Control**

Ubuntu One puts you in control of which folders you want to keep on your desktop and in your personal cloud. You select which folders you want to sync to your desktop or mobile so you can make the best use of space on all your devices. You can also access everything from the web at any time.

Subscribe [HERE!](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/subscribe-base/)

Comment: ah, as soon as I had completed the registration, I saw it.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your welcome Sir. Please mark this post as accepted if my answer helps you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will have 5 GB of storage upon registration, but you can get more.

[Directly quoting from the Faq](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-much-free-storage-can-i-get/)

> **How much free storage can I get?**
>
> Every Ubuntu One user can invite a maximum of 40 people which will earn you an extra 20GB of cloud storage absolutely free! It’s super easy, just send the referrals link which can be found in the [Ubuntu One dashboard](https://one.ubuntu.com/dashboard) to all your friends and family via email or Twitter and Facebook